# Xubuntu pyNeighborhood won't start

Tags: 11.10, python, xubuntu

I just installed pyNeighborhood on a freshly set up Xubuntu 11.10-machine via apt-get from the official repositories, however it won't start.

Error when starting via terminal:

```
user@pc:~$ pyNeighborhood 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyNeighborhood", line 23, in <module>
    from pyneighborhood.mainwindow import MainWindow
ImportError: No module named pyneighborhood.mainwindow
```

Anyone got an idea what could have gone wrong here?
Dependencies of the package should be fulfilled...

Thanks
-obs-

Comment: The pyneighborhood package has been orphaned: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=543880 - Try 0.5.4 from PPA: https://launchpad.net/~pyneighborhood/+archive/stable

Answer (score 1):

It works on lubuntu, it should work on xubuntu, at least run and appear normally.

Check that you have python-support installed:

```
sudo apt-get install python-support
```

Try purging and installing again.

```
sudo apt-get purge pyneighborhood
sudo apt-get install pyneighborhood
pyNeighborhood
```

Also, please check that you are using a package from the official repositories. I know it's freshly installed, but perhaps it's a repository mirror problem. This command will show the currently used version:

```
apt-cache policy pyneighborhood
```

This is my output:

```
pyneighborhood:
  Installed: 0.5.1
  Candidate: 0.5.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.5.1 0
        500 http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```